# response text undefined asp.net code behind

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

```
var req = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            url: 'loc.aspx?count=' + str,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            data:'{}',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });
        req.fail(function (data) {
        TINY.box.show({ html: 'Server Error. Try again: ' + data.responseText, animate: false, close: false, boxid: 'error', top: 100 });
        });
```

the above code used to work right in jsp, now i am trying to use in asp.net c#, any way I am getting correct data in error block which i want it in success block. Even `data.d` is not helping,

If i write something like `alert(data)` i am getting the complete html, I need just the response text, When i use like this `data.responseText`, I am getting undefined. Someone help pls.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have a `responseText` field in response json at all? Please note that data passed to jquery success function is already parsed by jquery and you are working not with XMLHttpRequest. Basically, your data should be a javascript object, if you return a json string from server.  Try to do `console.log(data)` and see in console what is returned.

Comment: Also, does your server return a json? Or maybe simple html?

Comment: Replace dataType: 'text' with  dataType:'json' and try out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below should work fine. I've added some comments where you are doing a mistake

```
var req = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            url: 'loc.aspx?count=' + str,
            dataType: 'html',// as you return a simple html dataType:json will throw an error as jquery will not be able to parse received string
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            data:'{}',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);// data is not an XHR object. it is a processed response. In your case - simple string with HTML which, of course, has no method responseText
            }
        });
        req.fail(function (data) {
        TINY.box.show({ html: 'Server Error. Try again: ' + data.responseText, animate: false, close: false, boxid: 'error', top: 100 });
        });
```

In `.fail` function you have `data.responseText` because in this case XHR object is passed as a first parameter (See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)). At the same time, first parameter of `success` callback is a clean data received with request. If without details, you can think that `data == xhr.responseText` in success callback. See success property description in [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) section

**upd**

As appeared, problem is not only with JS. I guess you have a simple `.aspx` page which is called with ajax. There are two solutions:

1) Use webservice instead. It will be better because it does not go through complete page load cycle and should be executed faster. And it will not produce unused HTML

2) aspx page will output some HTML by default. Before you return a response for ajax request, you should clear response (so HTML which is already generated will not be sent to a server), write your response and immediately end it:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Write("hello");
Response.End();
```

This way you should receive only `hello` in success.

Comment: see now that alert in success is giving me the complete HTML, I just need the response text which i wrote in c#, assume its "hello"

Comment: I cannot use firefox in my office, so no firebug also

Comment: IE and chrome also has similar tools.

Comment: See updated answer for how to remove unused HTML from response

Comment: I used a httpHandler for that purpose, What u said may be true, i dint try Response.clear. That may work. Thank you